# Help with basic ordinal arithmetic: What is the supremum of the sequence $\omega^{2} + \omega$, $\omega^{2}*2 + \omega$, $\omega^{2}*3 + \omega$, ...?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, transfinite-recursion

I need some help with some basic ordinal arithmetic. I am trying to determine the supremum of the sequence $\omega^{2}*1 + \omega$, $\omega^{2}*2 + \omega$, $\omega^{2}*3 + \omega$, ... where the sequence $1$, $2$, $3$, ... is the natural number sequence.

I think that the answer is $\omega^{3}$. My reasoning is a little clumsy, though. Suppose we replaced the $+$ $\omega$ term with $+$ $\omega^{2}$ instead. Then, the sequence would simply be: $\omega^{2}*2$, $\omega^{2}*3$, $\omega^{2}*4$, ..., which obviously has supremum $\omega^{3}$. Now, the original sequence clearly can't be any greater than this sequence, and since it also involves $\omega$ many $\omega^{2}$ terms, it must be at least $\omega^{3}$. Thus, the answer is $\omega^{3}$.

(1) Is this answer correct?
(2) What would a more elegant proof be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your idea is as elegant as it gets, but personally I'd rather be more efficient with my theorems.

Ordinal operations $+$ and $*$ are strictly increasing in the second variable and weakly increasing in the first variable (and, for the record, so is exponentiation as long as the base is $\ge2$). Therefore for all $n<\omega$ we have $$\omega^2* n+\omega< \omega^2*n+\omega^2=\omega^2*(n+1)<\omega^3$$

Therefore $\sup_{n<\omega} (\omega^2*n+\omega)\le \omega^3$.

Moreover, $\omega^2*n+\omega>\omega^2*n$, therefore $\sup_{n<\omega}(\omega^2*n+\omega)\ge \sup_{n<\omega}\omega^2*n=\omega^3$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll need to read more on the increasing behavior of + and *.